# initial user data for mysql server

Tags: mysql

What are the initial user data for a Mysql server (version 14.14 for Linux, i. e. 5.7.25)? All sources I can find say that the initial user is "root" and the password is either empty or "password". However, neither works. Both return an "access denied" error.

Comment: Have you tried using `mysql_secure_installation` to set it up?

Comment: While installing on Linux, there should've been a prompt to put in a password, but you can reject and leave it blank. Are you trying to access mysql through some other software or framework? e.g. Laravel?

Comment: I haven't used mysql_secure_installation and I didn't get a prompt to put in a password. Yet I'm just trying to use mysql over a command line.